# Getting an error using Dagger and having a base class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have just started to use Retrofit, Dagger & MVP and I ran into a problem that I don’t quite understand.

I have an API component & module that looks like this:

ApiModule:

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {
    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton
    public Api provideApi(RestAdapter restAdapter){
        return restAdapter.create(Api.class);
    }

    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton
    public RestAdapter provideRestAdapter(){
        return ApiRestAdapter.getInstance();
    }
}
```

ApiComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApiModule.class
})
public interface ApiComponent {
    Api api();

    void inject(BaseActivity activity);
}
```

I have a base activity that looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    protected Api api; //this can be used by any activity that is extending BaseActivity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //create the api component
        ApiComponent component = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                .apiModule(new ApiModule())
                .build();

        component.inject(this);//perform field injection
    }
}
```

This way any class can have access to the Api class to do whatever they want to do with that.
I also have an activity called WalkthroughActivity that implements a View and has a Presenter that is going to be injected. I created a module and component for that too. 
WalkthroughActivityModule:

```
@Module
public class WalkthroughActivityModule {

    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton
    public WalkthroughActivityPresenter providePresenter(){
        return new WalkthroughActivityPresenter();
    }
}
```

WalkthroughActivityComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                WalkthroughActivityModule.class
        }
)
public interface WalkthroughActivityComponent {

    WalkthroughActivityPresenter walkthroughActivityPresenter();

    void inject(WalkthroughActivity walkthroughActivity);
}
```

WalkthroughActivity:

```
public class WalkthroughActivity extends BaseActivity implements WalkthroughActiviyView {

    @Inject WalkthroughActivityPresenter walkthroughActivityPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walkthrough);

        DaggerWalkthroughActivityComponent.builder()
                .walkthroughActivityModule(new WalkthroughActivityModule())
                .build()
                .inject(this);

        showWalkthroughPager();
    }
 }
```

I get an error saying this:

```
Error:(26, 10) error: com.myapp.api.Api cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
com.myapp.ui.base.BaseActivity.api
[injected field of type: com.myapp.api.Api api]
```

My immediate guess is that it has something to do with WalkThorughActivity extending BaseActivity. Or maybe it has to do with Scoping. But I don’t quite understand how to wrap my head around this. Could someone please explain why this is happening.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You inject dependencies for  WalkthroughActivity in WalkthroughActivityComponent which has no idea about ApiModule

2) You can't inject dependencies through parent class. You should do something like this

```
class BaseActivity {
    @Inject Foo foo
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ApiComponent component = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                .apiModule(new ApiModule())
                .build();
        injectDependencies(component)
    }

    public abstract void injectDependencies(Component component);
}

class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void injectDependencies(ApiComponent component) {
        component.inject(this);
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApiModule.class
})
public interface ApiComponent {
    Api api();
    void inject(ChildActivity activity); // Injecting into child object
}
```

Comment: What happens when i need to inject multiple components? So what if i want to inject WalkthroughActivityComponent & ApiComponent inside WalkthroughActivity?

Comment: You could inject ApiComponent in overridden method and WalkthroughActivityComponent in WalkthroughActivity#onCreate() after calling super.onCreate. Or you could have getter for ApiComponent on BaseActivity and use it inside injectDepencencies to get required component. This way you doesn't have to pass component to this method and in the future could add other components. For example if your WalkthroughActivity needed dependecy from some application level component you could implement getter for that component on Application class and call it in appropriate injectDependency method.